# Migrate data from Citus to RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-migration, dms, citus

Since Citus is not going to be available as a Managed Service in AWS, I am trying move the database to RDS (not the whole history but only the transactional portion as an OLTP). The migration from Citus is not clear because the data does not reside in a single node. I want to check the options we might have to move data from Citus to RDS.

Amazon DMS: This option is good for the supported databases (PostgreSQL) but we do not know what behavior this will have in Citus from the distributed nature of the engine. Has someone migrated the data to S3, to another DB or something in these lines?
I saw this paper from AWS https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-cloud-data-ingestion-patterns-practices.pdf?did=wp_card&trk=wp_card on how to ingest data from different sources and DMS seems like a good option but I do not know the internals of Citus that well to tell if we will get all the data and gather the CDC correctly.

A Custom migration: Via a support ticket, we can access the S3 buckets that Citus uses for Disaster recovery where the WAL logs are available and we could use something like WAL-G to take those logs and replicate them in a Postgres instance. The issue here is that this is a very custom migration and the development time might be too high.
Is there any other option to move data from Citus to RDS or Aurora in AWS, what looks like a good path to make the database migration? All the documents refer to move data the other way around, from Aurora or RDS to Citus.

Comment: What amount of downtime are you willing to tolerate?

Comment: The downtime could be around a couple of hours (2 hrs) and the amount of data is around 7 TB un something like 30 tables. Not a uniform distribution (some tables have 1~2 TB of data, some others have 2GB)

Comment: To complete the picture, what is the data change rate, and are some of the large tables immutable? Are you planning to migrate to RDS for PostgreSQL or to RDS Aurora PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Sumedh from Citus Cloud here. Please go ahead and open a support ticket with us to further investigate solutions. We can evaluate if using DMS is a viable approach for your use-case.